# Add animation as Marker google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps, animation

I wanted to add an animation as the "current marker selected" in my map as shown below:

[image]

The animation is a LottieAnimation resource (extends from ImageView).

I had been searching and google maps developer docs said that I can only use Bitmap resources as markers. I tried to convert this one as a bitmap but without success.

Uber or Lyft has some animations as markers or for current position, so how they achieve this?

Or is it possible that they are listening to the map movement and update the location of their marker without using the marker property?

Comment: From the animation you are showing it looks like they might just be placing an `ImageView` overlay and animating the image when map is moved or touched.

Comment: The image i am showing is my application. I want that ImageView to be over a marker, and move it accordingly when the map is moved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, Google map Marker and InfoWindow is drawn on the map as a flat bitmap. So you cannot do animation, component touch interaction or even draw a shadow around them officially.

Uber app uses a different layer placed on top of the map (You can try to do some gesture on the map and see that the marker move but a bit delay). It's not easy because you have to catch every map's gesture and animate the overlay view accordingly. I tried that before but it's too much work to do so I left it behind.

Your Pulse effect can be achieved using `Circle` with `ValueAnimator`

```
private @ColorInt int mPulseEffectColor;
private int[] mPulseEffectColorElements;
private ValueAnimator mPulseEffectAnimator;
private Circle mPulseCircle;


private void initPulseEffect() {
    mPulseEffectColor = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.pink);
    mPulseEffectColorElements = new int[] {
            Color.red(mPulseEffectColor),
            Color.green(mPulseEffectColor),
            Color.blue(mPulseEffectColor)
    };

    mPulseEffectAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, calculatePulseRadius(current_map_zoom_level));
    mPulseEffectAnimator.setStartDelay(3000);
    mPulseEffectAnimator.setDuration(400);
    mPulseEffectAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
}
```

Calculate radius base on map's zoom level

```
private static float calculatePulseRadius(float zoomLevel) {
    return (float) Math.pow(2, 16 - zoomLevel) * 160;
}
```

Register `OnCameraIdleListener` to listen to map's zoom changed

```
@Override
public void onCameraIdle() {
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = mMap.getCameraPosition();
    if (mPulseEffectAnimator != null)
        mPulseEffectAnimator.setFloatValues(0, calculatePulseRadius(cameraPosition.zoom));
}
```

Start the animation

```
private void startPulseAnimation() {
    if (mPulseCircle != null)
        mPulseCircle.remove();

    if (mPulseEffectAnimator != null) {
        mPulseEffectAnimator.removeAllUpdateListeners();
        mPulseEffectAnimator.removeAllListeners();
        mPulseEffectAnimator.end();
    }

    if (your_marker_coordinate != null) {
        mPulseCircle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(your_marker_coordinate)
                .radius(0).strokeWidth(0)
                .fillColor(mPulseEffectColor));
        mPulseEffectAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                if (mPulseCircle == null)
                    return;

                int alpha = (int) ((1 - valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction()) * 128);
                mPulseCircle.setFillColor(Color.argb(alpha,
                        mPulseEffectColorElements[0], mPulseEffectColorElements[1], mPulseEffectColorElements[2]));
                mPulseCircle.setRadius((float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });
        mPulseEffectAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mPulseEffectAnimator.setStartDelay(2000);
                mPulseEffectAnimator.start();
            }
        });
        mPulseEffectAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- Use `calculatePulseRadius` to recalculate the radius base on the map zoom level, because the circle's radius is measured by the real-world distance.
- Use `int[] mPulseEffectColorElements` to store r,g,b of the circle color so I don't have to recreate the color every frame. I only want to change the alpha value
- Listen to Animator end and start it again with delay.

This code only applied for 1 circle at a time, multiple circles require harder work but same logic.

Result:

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks Mark! I keep searching and I found this: https://github.com/DroidsOnRoids/Workcation . It explains how to do this type of animation on maps, you have to use an overlay mask and mimic all the gestures as you said! I just wanted to make myself clear if this was the only way.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will take a look. The overlay mask is worth trying because your animation has better performance and you have full control just like the normal view animation. Animate map `Circle` radius and color like I did may get laggy sometimes and not very flexible.